# JSON in MySQL : get data from an object within a range of keys

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb-10.4, json-path

#### What I have:

- A `mysql` table, say `table1`
- `table1` contains two columns viz. `id` and `data`
- `id` is `int` but the twist is `data` is `JSON` type and *its keys are comparable*
- the `table1` contains ***only one row*** *(for the sake of this question)*

**table1**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'1': 'content1', '2': 'content2', '3':'content3',.......,'10000':'content10000' } |

#### What I want to have:

I want a query such that it returns me key-value pairs within a range of keys, say, 100 to 200.

#### What I'm getting on searching on internet:

Everywhere I got only the answers where one can get rows which have the values within a range, but here the case is I want values of keys within a range.

Comment: for starters which mysql version are you using? basically json is bad for such problems, mysql 8 has json_table which simplifies it somewhat, still json is bad if you want that information directly from mysql, store tem in a normal relational table and it gets easy

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 10.4

Comment: Synthetic numbers list and JOIN.

Comment: @Akina the oath must be strings or not`?

Comment: @nbk Generated numbers will be used for to build JSON paths - so number during generation and string finally.

Comment: The task is rather trivial in any client language that parses JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible realization:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT @from num
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT num+1 FROM cte WHERE num < @till )
SELECT CONCAT('key', num) `key`, 
       JSON_EXTRACT(test.val, CONCAT('$.key', num)) `value`
FROM test
CROSS JOIN cte
HAVING `value` IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=070a21007b7de963fe840bdc8fe0a768)

Comment: Thanks @Akina, learned something new today.